# How do I correctly reference georss: point in my xsd?

Tags: xml, import, xsd, georss

I am putting together an XSD schema to describe an existing GeoRSS feed, but I am stumbling trying to use the external georss.xsd to validate an element of type `georss:point`. I've reduced the problem to the smallest components thusly:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<this>
    <apoint>45.256 -71.92</apoint>
</this>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.georss.org/georss"
           schemaLocation="http://georss.org/xml/1.1/georss.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="this">
        <xs:complexType>    
            <xs:sequence>    
                <xs:element name="apoint" type="georss:point"/>   
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>   
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If I make apoint type "xs: string" instead of "georss: point", the XML validates happily against the XSD, but as soon as I reference an imported type (georss: point), my XML validator (Notepad++ | XML Tools) "cannot parse the schema".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nicely worded question Chris. Have you tried validating the XML with other validators? You could confirm it's a problem with your markup and not the tool this way.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I downloaded Oxygen which generated the XSD automatically for me, which I then reloaded back into Notepad++. Yes, it validated. The XSD it created is a long way from what I had written, it will take some time to decode to understand the differences and what I was missing. However, in the meantime, it gave me what I need - an XSD! So, I'll take that as a win! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the question, you were referring to a non-existent type. Below is what you're working with:

[image]

If you want the point element, then you reference it (as you did afterwards). If you want to reuse the type (content model) with your own tag then your `apoint`'s type should've been `doubleList`.

It is not uncommon to reuse a type, since it is a method to maximize the "shutout" of unwanted XML namespaces from instance XML (see [Venetian blind authoring style](http://www.w3.org/2005/07/xml-schema-patterns.html#Naming)). In your case, you would've achieved a namespace-free XML.

Answer (score 0):

The final working example of a solution to what I was trying to achieve was as follows:

XML:

```
<rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
    <georss:point>-41.295781753436 173.229502017379</georss:point>
</rss>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.georss.org/georss" schemaLocation="georss.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="rss">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="georss:point"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The key is the use of the 'ref' attribute to refer to the imported type.

```
<xs:element ref="georss:point"/>
```